# javascript table keeps repeating itself

Tags: javascript, html

I got a problem with a website i made. The problem is when i add items to the cart it makes a table. 
But when i change the amount of products and add it again to the cart it makes table row beneath the existing.

This is my HTML and JS code i got so far:

So the best thing i want is that when an item is already in the table. It get  replaced by the same item but with the new amount.

```
if (cat == "T")
            {
                //variable die worden aangemaakt voor de final bestel form
                artikelbestelT= [];
                prijsbestelT = [];
                aantalbestelT =[];
                //hier worden alle value aangesproken door middel van een dynamische benaming met een for loop 
                for (teller = 0; teller< artikeltel.length; teller++)
            {

                var waardeelem = document.getElementById("selecties"+teller+"");
                var waarde = waardeelem.options[waardeelem.selectedIndex].value;
                // hier wordt totaal berekent voor in winkelmandje
                totaal= prijstel[teller] * waarde;
                //hier wordt totaal in een array gestopt voor het eindbedrag
                eindbedragT[teller] = totaal;
                // als er niks wordt ingevuld kwa waarde dus 0 producten wordt dit stuk over geslagen
                if (waarde > 0)
                {
                    //anders wordt er een niewe array gemaakt met de daadwerkelijk bestelde producten
                    artikelbestelT.push(artikeltel[teller]) ;
                    prijsbestelT.push(prijstel[teller]);
                    aantalbestelT.push(waarde);
                    //hier wordt een tabel( winkelmandje ) gemaakt met de huidige producten
                    var table = document.getElementById("tabel");
            var rowcount= table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowcount);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
            cell1.innerHTML = artikeltel[teller];
            cell2.innerHTML = prijstel[teller];
            cell3.innerHTML = waarde;
            cell4.innerHTML = totaal;

                }
```

dear all. Thanks so far for the comments. I cleaned up the code to the part where i make the table. 
So everytime i change the value of how many items he wants ( that is variabele "waarde") than he doesnt delete the old table but just put it beneath the existing.

I hope it clears it up a little bit :)

Comment: Come on now.  Please reduce the included code to ONLY the relevant portion (e.g. the portion that cause the problem with the table).

Comment: That's a lot of code for people to sift through.  Do some debugging and narrow down the issue.  When you step through the code in a debugger, at what point does it deviate from the expected behavior?

Comment: Than write some code that looks at the table and updates the amount.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have so much code, I'm not gonna bother looking through it all, but I'll just take a guess instead: You are simply appending any changes to the html onto the exist table rows. If this is the case, then I would suggest the simple solution of erasing the existing html for the table each update, and replacing it with all with the current cart contents (which you should be storing separately from the displayed html table already).

You could also give ids to each row that is unique to that item, and then access the quantity cell for the specific item you are changing, and change that text to reflect the new quantity.